# Best way to handle SEO URLs with PHP

Tags: php, seo

I've got a PHP file called books.php, and I'd like to use SEO URLs using htaccess and PHP.

I would like to create rules for the following formats:
`books.php?bookid=X` (Optional: `books.php?bookid=X&page=Y`)
`books.php?categoryid=X` (Optional: `books.php?categoryid=X&page=Y`)
`books.php?do=search&query=X`
`books.php?do=search&tag=X`

These would be accessible through:
`/books/book/{booktitle}`
`/books/category/{categorytitle}`
`/books/search/{search_string}`
`/books/tags/{tagtext}`

What I'd like to know is the main idea for doing this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it's easier to just do something like this:

```
/books/book/9834/{title}
```

Where the number is the database ID, and the plain-text title is just thrown away by the PHP. It's not as clean, but there's too many problems involving uniqueness if you try to pass the title in to a SQL query IMO.

Check out the [mod-rewrite generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/) here for help building rules.

Comment: that's what stackoverflow does for example... and it's one of the best  solution in general

Comment: I see, I'll consider this, thanks. What if I were to do it using PHP though? Is it just impossible to do it right?

Comment: Also, the solution you had brought up is sort of problematic. It needs to be `/books/book/9834/{title}` or else it could case problems (in case there's also a category with the same id and title).

Comment: You can use any back end language... most of the legwork is done by mod_rewrite

Comment: @Chris Sobolewski So in case I do choose using title only, with out an id, what am I supposed to do? `explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`, then get the row that matches to the 3rd key of the array from the database? That's it?

Answer (score 4):

The key piece here actually happens outside of PHP. You want to tell your webserver that instead of just looking for a file or directory with the given name, you actually want /books/foo/bar to call books.php with foo and bar as parameters. If you're using Apache, take a look at this: [htaccess mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188225/htaccess-mod-rewrite)

Once you get this set up, I would recommend redirecting all the old books.php URLs to their new "SEO URL" equivalent. Best practice is to have exactly one valid URL for each page.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a [micro-framework](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html) or a [full-blown framework](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html)?

This is the kind of problems they solve, so you can focus on building your application instead of building your tools.