# htaccess ModRewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to make *rewrite* from

```
http://site.com/pages/123
```

to

```
http://site.com/pages.php?id=123
```

with htaccess and modrewrite?

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to a less-friendly URL? Did you perhaps mean *rewrite*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188225/htaccess-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to *rewrite* the URL instead of *redirecting*, try this in a `.htaccess` file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^pages/(\d+) pages.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the example 123 can just be numbers:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]*)$ pages.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to rewrite the URL instead of redirecting, try this in a .htaccess file in your document root

```
#Rewrite Rules
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule    ^pages/(.*)/?$  pages.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
```