# is there any way to remove or hide the controller name in url? codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I developed a project in php codeigniter. The project is almost complete but now my manager wants me to completely remove or hide the controller names in the URL. My current URL looks like this:

> http://www.sitename.com/Controller_Name/function_name

and my manager wants it to look like this:

> http://www.sitename.com/function_name

Note that I have more than 10 controllers in my project and many many functions. I want a method that applies to all. HELP PLEASE.

Comment: you can use url rewriting

Comment: did you check this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12863095/how-to-remove-controller-name-from-url-making-it-clean-in-codeigniter ...?

Comment: You can do it, but in your case I don't think you can use a method that applies to all...

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using `$route`.

If you have only one `Controller` and in that controller you all the `functions` you can write something like this:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "Controller_Name/$1";
```

If you have many `Controllers` you need to specify for each `function` to what controller to point. Like this:

```
$route['function1'] = "Controller_Name1/function1";
$route['function2'] = "Controller_Name1/function2";
$route['function3'] = "Controller_Name3/function3";
```

And you can't have duplicates in `$route`

This `$route` array should be located here: `application/config/routes.php`.

You can check more about routes on the CI documentation here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your controller and method name in routes file like below

$route['function_name'] = 'controller_name/function_name';

You have to write this for each function in controller.By doing you get two advantages

1) Controller name will be hidden in your url
2) you can call some method by its name only.No need to use controller name every time.