# SEO Friendly URL (with .htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to add friendly URL's to my website. But I have one problem. I've never used .htaccess.

My link:

```
https://example.com/index.php?page=users
```

I would like to have an URL like this:

```
https://example.com/page/users
```

OR

```
https://example.com/users
```

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188225/htaccess-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved with:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
```

So it is very simple.