# Seo-Friendly url's with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I already found several topics and questions regarding this, but it seems everything I'm trying to do doesn't do what it is supposed to do:

.htaccess-file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1
```

As you can tell, nothing to special. This example was taken from this solution here: [SEO Friendly URL (with .htaccess)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297187/seo-friendly-url-with-htaccess)

From my example:

```
http://example.org/index.php?site=delivery
```

should result in

```
http://example.org/Delivery # If it is possible, a capitalized Letter would be cool
```

I can call the Site manually, but references (to *.css-files) aren't included anymore. Furthermore, the RewriteBase doesn't seem to work.

I added some buggy code to verify that the .htaccess file is loaded (and it is).

If I linke something with `<a href="index.php?site=mySite">` - does the URL automagically change to the specific rule? Yes, right? But what could be missing, that the rules aren't applying?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule is fine. Because of the rewrite, you have to handle relative links differently now.

So once the rule is in place. You need to add this to the `<head>` section of your html.

```
<base href="http://www.yoursite.com" />
```

Then your JS and CSS will load while using the rule. It's not a .htaccess rule problem.

> If I linke something with  - does the
>   URL automagically change to the specific rule?

No it does not. You need a rule for that too.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond {THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+index\.php\?site=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1
```